# Android Emulator not enough space

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have set my sdcard size and internal storage size to 1gb each, but if you look at the screenshot, I don't have anywhere close to as much space. I've attached an image of my setup. Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

[image]